Why does the query gone when i fill any form on livewire
So i have this condition on livewire

        @if (request()->query('program') == 'high-school')
        <div class="mb-4">
            <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
                <div>
                    <label for="instance" class="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mb-2">Instance</label>
                    <select id="instance" class="w-full px-4 py-2 border rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-500" wire:model.lazy="instance">
                        <option value="null" selected disabled>{{ __('Please select') }}</option>
                        @foreach($dataInstance as $instance)
                            <option value="{{ $instance->id }}">{{ $instance->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="program" class="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mb-2">Program</label>
                    <select id="program" class="w-full px-4 py-2 border rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-500" wire:model.lazy="program">
                        <option value="null" selected disabled>{{ __('Please select') }}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @else
        <div class="mb-4">
            <label for="instance" class="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mb-2">Instance</label>
            <select id="instance" class="w-full px-4 py-2 border rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-500" wire:model="instance" wire:change="fetchFaculties">
                <option value="null" selected disabled>{{ __('Please select') }}</option>
                @foreach($dataInstance as $instance)
                    <option value="{{ $instance->id }}">{{ $instance->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-4">
            <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
                <div>
                    <label for="faculty" class="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mb-2">Faculty</label>
                    <select id="faculty" class="w-full px-4 py-2 border rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-500" wire:model="faculty" wire:change="fetchPrograms">
                        <option value="null" selected disabled>{{ __('Please select') }}</option>
                        @foreach($faculties as $faculty)
                            <option value="{{ $faculty->id }}">{{ $faculty->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="program" class="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mb-2">Program</label>
                    <select id="program" class="w-full px-4 py-2 border rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-500" wire:model.lazy="program">
                        <option value="null" selected disabled>{{ __('Please select') }}</option>
                        @foreach($programs as $program)
                            <option value="{{ $program->id }}">{{ $program->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endif

And this is the controller
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Homepage;

use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Models\Instance;
use App\Models\Intern;
use App\Models\InstanceFaculty;
use App\Models\InstanceProgram;
use App\Models\Province;
use App\Models\Regency;
use App\Models\District;
use Mail;
use App\Mail\VerificationEmail;

class Register extends Component
{
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $password_confirmation;
    public $phone;
    public $nik;
    public $domicile;
    public $instance;
    public $faculty;
    public $program;
    public $province;
    public $regency;
    public $district;
    public $dataInstance;
    public $dataProvinces;

    public function updated($field)
    {
        $this->validateOnly($field, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:interns,email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
            'phone' => 'required|unique:interns,phone',
            'nik' => 'required|unique:interns,nik',
            'domicile' => 'required',
            'instance' => 'required',
            'province' => 'required',
            'regency' => 'required',
            'district' => 'required',
        ]);
    }

    public function mount()
    {
        $level = request()->query('program');

        if ($level == "high-school") {
            $level = "High School";
        } else {
            $level = "University";
        }

        $this->dataInstance = Instance::where('level', $level)->get();
        $this->dataProvinces = Province::all();
    }

    public function fetchFaculties()
    {
        $faculties = InstanceFaculty::where('instance_id', $this->instance)->get();

        return $faculties;
    }

    public function fetchPrograms()
    {
        $programs = InstanceProgram::where('faculty_id', $this->faculty)->get();

        return $programs;
    }

    public function fetchRegency()
    {
        $regencies = Regency::where('province_id', $this->province)->get();

        return $regencies;
    }

    public function fetchDistrict()
    {
        $districts = District::where('regency_id', $this->regency)->get();

        return $districts;
    }

    public function processRegistration()
    {
        $validatedData = $this->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:interns,email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
            'phone' => 'required|unique:interns,phone',
            'nik' => 'required|unique:interns,nik',
            'instance' => 'required',
            'program' => 'required',
            'province' => 'required',
            'regency' => 'required',
            'district' => 'required',
        ]);

        $verification_token = Str::random(40);

        $domicile = $this->province . ", " . $this->regency . ", " . $this->district;

        $intern = Intern::create([
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'password' => bcrypt($this->password),
            'phone' => $this->phone,
            'nik' => $this->nik,
            'domicile' => $domicile,
            'instance_id' => $this->instance,
            'verification_token' => $verification_token,
        ]);

        Mail::to($this->email)->send(new VerificationEmail($intern));

        return redirect('/login');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.homepage.register', [
            'dataInstance' => $this->dataInstance,
            'faculties' => $this->fetchFaculties(),
            'programs' => $this->fetchPrograms(),
            'regencies' => $this->fetchRegency(),
            'districts' => $this->fetchDistrict(),
        ])->layout('livewire.layout.authentication');
    }
}

Im using query as conditions. the problem is, the query gone when i fill any form. for example, if i im on ?program=high-school, and i fill any form, it will change to the else condition.
I want the condition stay still when i fill any form
